# Moving TYPO3 Project to local environment with Xampp Apache Server

Tags: php, typo3, local

first off, I'm new to TYPO3.
We use TYPO3 to manage our Webiste. Now I want to make some changes to it and try them out in a local environment so I can't mess up stuff!
I pulled all data from our FTP server and tried to put it in the htdocs folder of xampp which I use to run the apache server.
When I try to run the site, I get an error related to the TYPO3 "realurl.php" file.
At this point I have no clue how to succeed with this problem.

**Warning: Undefined variable $rssFeedPageType in C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3conf\realurl.php on line 35**

Since I pulled all Data from the FTP Server, I'm not sure why this happens.

[image: Screenshot realurl.php]

[image: Screenshot AdditionalConfig.php]

[image: Chrome errors]

**Errorlog:**

```
[Thu Mar 17 15:17:47.861341 2022] [php:warn] [pid 14632:tid 1968] [client ::1:56627] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "t3lib/class.t3lib_div.php" in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Utility\\GeneralUtility.php on line 5125
[Thu Mar 17 15:17:47.862340 2022] [php:warn] [pid 14632:tid 1968] [client ::1:56627] PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Utility\\GeneralUtility.php on line 5125
[Thu Mar 17 15:17:47.863338 2022] [php:warn] [pid 14632:tid 1968] [client ::1:56627] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "ORIG_SCRIPT_NAME" in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Utility\\GeneralUtility.php on line 3438
[Thu Mar 17 15:17:47.864344 2022] [php:warn] [pid 14632:tid 1968] [client ::1:56627] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "systemLog" in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Utility\\GeneralUtility.php on line 5083
[Thu Mar 17 15:17:47.865359 2022] [php:warn] [pid 14632:tid 1968] [client ::1:56627] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 1 in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Utility\\GeneralUtility.php on line 5092
[Thu Mar 17 15:17:47.868338 2022] [php:error] [pid 14632:tid 1968] [client ::1:56627] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Error\\TYPO3_ERROR_DLOG" in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Error\\ErrorHandler.php:134\n
Stack trace:\n
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Utility\\GeneralUtility.php(3453): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Error\\ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'Undefined array...', 'C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...', 3453)\n
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Utility\\GeneralUtility.php(3596): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Utility\\GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('REQUEST_URI')\n
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Error\\AbstractExceptionHandler.php(73): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Utility\\GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_REQUEST_U...')\n
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Error\\ProductionExceptionHandler.php(56): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Error\\AbstractExceptionHandler->writeLogEntries(Object(Error), 'WEB')\n
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Error\\AbstractExceptionHandler.php(45): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Error\\ProductionExceptionHandler->echoExceptionWeb(Object(Error))\n
#5 [internal function]: TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Error\\AbstractExceptionHandler->handleException(Object(Error))\n
#6 {main}\n  thrown in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Error\\ErrorHandler.php on line 134
```

Comment: Uncomment line 8?

Comment: is it possible for you to access the backend or install tool?

Comment: i tried that already. if i do so, i get "HTTP Error 500"

Comment: @KreutzerCode accessing the backend is what i tried to do. thats where i get the Error "undefined variable..." if i uncomment the variable, i get "HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: Check your PHP error log for what is causing the 500 response.

Comment: If you have access to the install tool, check if TYPO3 has all necessary permissions to write files and folders. I'm pretty sure you'll need to re-generalize the RealURL paths for local development. But I am not sure if this is related to your error.

Comment: @cOle2 i put the errorlog in the Post. Tough this doesnt really get **me** anywhere :/

Comment: @KreutzerCode can i re-generalize the RealURL paths without the install tool? so far i couldnt access it.

Comment: @KreutzerCode i can only access the backend on the online environment.

Comment: i don't know any way to do this without accessing the backend / install tool. If you can't even get into the install tool, I recommend removing the realURL extension from PackageStates.php. This deactivates the extension, maybe you can get access to the backend / install tool again.

Comment: @KreutzerCode unfortunately nothing changed after removing the realURL extension from the PackageStates.php.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing: Correct PHP version?

- If your TYPO3 is still using EXT:realurl, it's at most a TYPO3 8.7.
- "Undefined array key" warnings are thrown typically by PHP 8.x (which
  might be default in a fresh XAMPP installation).
- TYPO3 8.7 is only compatible with PHP 7.4. So far, PHP 8 is only
  supported by TYPO3 v11.

Comment: okay, thats a good hint i guess. The Typo Version is 7.6.14 and the installed php version i have is 8.1.2.